# Laravel multi tenant migrate

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Wondering if anyone knows how or of a package that allows migrations to be done on multiple databases without having the additional connection in the config file. Currently I have two different connections, one for the default and another for the tenants. The tenant connection has the credentials input, but it doesn't have the database name since each tenant will have a different database name. Problem is when I'm doing the initial setup and need the migrations to be run it will do it for the default or the tenant(if I edit the file to include the database name). I had found a package that would do it but it is not currently compatible with laravel 5. Obviously if I have to do it manually it can be done. It would just be a pain. Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the tenancy related questions here, I stumbled upon your open one.

What I've done is override the default MigrateCommand provided by Laravel and add the `--tenant` option. This will allow me to migrate one, more or all tenants. You can check the implementation out [at my repository](https://github.com/hyn/multi-tenant/blob/master/src/Commands/Migrate/MigrateCommand.php). Knowing the code of conduct here, I'll also add an example implementation:

```
<?php

namespace Hyn\MultiTenant\Commands\Migrate;

use Hyn\MultiTenant\Traits\TenantDatabaseCommandTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator;
use PDOException;

class MigrateCommand extends \Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand
{
    use TenantDatabaseCommandTrait;

    /**
     * MigrateCommand constructor.
     *
     * @param Migrator $migrator
     */
    public function __construct(Migrator $migrator)
    {
        parent::__construct($migrator);

        $this->website = app('Hyn\MultiTenant\Contracts\WebsiteRepositoryContract');
    }

    public function fire()
    {

        // fallback to default behaviour if we're not talking about multi tenancy
        if (! $this->option('tenant')) {
            $this->info('No running tenancy migration, falling back on native laravel migrate command due to missing tenant option.');

            return parent::fire();
        }

        if (! $this->option('force') && ! $this->confirmToProceed()) {
            $this->error('Stopped no confirmation and not forced.');

            return;
        }

        $websites = $this->getWebsitesFromOption();

        // forces database to tenant
        if (! $this->option('database')) {
            $this->input->setOption('database', 'tenant');
        }

        foreach ($websites as $website) {
            $this->info("Migrating for {$website->id}: {$website->present()->name}");

            $website->database->setCurrent();

            $this->prepareDatabase($website->database->name);

            // The pretend option can be used for "simulating" the migration and grabbing
            // the SQL queries that would fire if the migration were to be run against
            // a database for real, which is helpful for double checking migrations.
            $pretend = $this->input->getOption('pretend');

            // Next, we will check to see if a path option has been defined. If it has
            // we will use the path relative to the root of this installation folder
            // so that migrations may be run for any path within the applications.
            if (! is_null($path = $this->input->getOption('path'))) {
                $path = $this->laravel->basePath().'/'.$path;
            } else {
                $path = $this->getMigrationPath();
            }

            try {
                $this->migrator->run($path, $pretend);
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                if (str_contains($e->getMessage(), ['Base table or view already exists'])) {
                    $this->comment("Migration failed for existing table; probably a system migration: {$e->getMessage()}");
                    continue;
                }
            }

            // Once the migrator has run we will grab the note output and send it out to
            // the console screen, since the migrator itself functions without having
            // any instances of the OutputInterface contract passed into the class.
            foreach ($this->migrator->getNotes() as $note) {
                $this->output->writeln($note);
            }
        }

        // Finally, if the "seed" option has been given, we will re-run the database
        // seed task to re-populate the database, which is convenient when adding
        // a migration and a seed at the same time, as it is only this command.
        if ($this->input->getOption('seed')) {
            $this->call('db:seed', ['--force' => true, '--tenant' => $this->option('tenant')]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Prepare the migration database for running.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function prepareDatabase($connection = null)
    {
        if (! $connection) {
            $connection = $this->option('database');
        }

        $this->migrator->setConnection($connection);

        if (! $this->migrator->repositoryExists()) {
            $options = ['--database' => $connection];

            $this->call('migrate:install', $options);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getOptions()
    {
        return array_merge(
            parent::getOptions(),
            $this->getTenantOption()
        );
    }
}
```

If you have any questions to solve this issue, let me know.